# How to dress when recording Foleys?

Tags: audio-recording, foley, sound-effects-recording, studio

Just discovered a 2014 short called [The Sound of COS](https://vimeo.com/103694372). It shows two guys creating Foleys for a fashion commercial. The short being sponsored by COS, of course the two are dressed sleekly. However, I expect such clothing to create unwanted sounds caused by rubbing of fabric.

*How do people dress when recording Foleys such as those shown in the short film?*

Answer (score 5):

shorts and a t shirt, to minimize clothing noise when doing a foot pass. clothing moves can be added separately. pants swishing noise can build up when doing multiple passes of feet.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of Foley artists use sweat pants, soft clothes that don't make sound when rubbing together. Also take off any jewely, belts, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If I know for sure there are no way anyone would see me, and I'm in my own studio - tee and boxers. In extreme cases also a thick Palestinian scarf (textured with skulls and crossbones for that extra audio push!) covering my mouth and nose to further reduce the risk of accidental breaths or such.

But mostly I use a tee washed with a lot of fabric softener and a pair of Adidas sweatpants in some sort of almost absolutely noiseless synthetic material that I got from my then girlfriend. I did for a while try to work with my Karate Gi-pants, but worn cotton can be very very noisy, I realized...